# mimeType for google-apps documents causes a server error if combined with many other mimeTypes

Tags: google-drive-api, mime-types

I'm building a searhString and want to include/exclude certain mimeTypes.

I noticed

```
var searchString = 
    "(trashed = false and hidden = false) and  ((mimeType='image/bmp') or (mimeType='image/gif') or (mimeType='image/jpeg') or (mimeType='image/png') or (mimeType='image/svg+xml') or (mimeType='image/tiff') or (mimeType='video/mp4') or (mimeType='video/ogg') or (mimeType='video/quicktime') or (mimeType='video/x-flv') or (mimeType='video/mpeg') or (mimeType='audio/mpeg') or (mimeType='audio/mpeg3') or (mimeType='audio/mp3') or (mimeType='audio/mp4') or (mimeType='audio/ogg') or (mimeType='text/csv') or (mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.document') or (mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') or (mimeType='application/msword') or (mimeType='application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text') or (mimeType='application/pdf') or (mimeType='text/plain') or (mimeType='application/rtf'))"

var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchString);
```

does work.

But trying to enclose the mineType part with `(not ....)` causes a server error

```
"(trashed = false and hidden = false) and (not ((mimeType='image/bmp') or (mimeType='image/gif') or (mimeType='image/jpeg') or (mimeType='image/png') or (mimeType='image/svg+xml') or (mimeType='image/tiff') or (mimeType='video/mp4') or (mimeType='video/ogg') or (mimeType='video/quicktime') or (mimeType='video/x-flv') or (mimeType='video/mpeg') or (mimeType='audio/mpeg') or (mimeType='audio/mpeg3') or (mimeType='audio/mp3') or (mimeType='audio/mp4') or (mimeType='audio/ogg') or (mimeType='text/csv') or (mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.document') or (mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') or (mimeType='application/msword') or (mimeType='application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text') or (mimeType='application/pdf') or (mimeType='text/plain') or (mimeType='application/rtf')))"
```

Likewise, if I change the searchstring into

```
  "(trashed = false and hidden = false) and (mimeType!='image/bmp') and (mimeType!='image/gif') and (mimeType!='image/jpeg') and (mimeType!='image/png') and (mimeType!='image/svg+xml') and (mimeType!='image/tiff') and (mimeType!='video/mp4') and (mimeType!='video/ogg') and (mimeType!='video/quicktime') and (mimeType!='video/x-flv') and (mimeType!='video/mpeg') and (mimeType!='audio/mpeg') and (mimeType!='audio/mpeg3') and (mimeType!='audio/mp3') and (mimeType!='audio/mp4') and (mimeType!='audio/ogg') and (mimeType!='text/csv') and (mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.document') and (mimeType!='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') and (mimeType!='application/msword') and (mimeType!='application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text') and (mimeType!='application/pdf') and (mimeType!='text/plain') and (mimeType!='application/rtf')"
```

the same error occurs.

But if I remove `(mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.document') and` from that searchString, it works.

If I put the that string in front of the other mimeTypes, I get the sme error again.

If I remove the string for google documents from the searchstring

```
  "(trashed = false and hidden = false) and ((mimeType!='image/bmp') and (mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.document'))"
```

it works.

Finally, if I try

```
  "(trashed = false and hidden = false) and (not ((mimeType='image/bmp') or (mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.document')))"
```

it also works

So for the moment, my conclusion is that `(mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.document')` is causing a problem combined with a large number of other mimeTypes.

Needles to say I would prefer to have an easier method for including / excluding certain mimetypes

Can anybody confirm my problem?
If so, where should I put a bugreport?
Does anybody know a way around the problem? (maybe chaining of search request, but how using GAS ?)

Comment: Are you using a client library?

Comment: No I wrote all myself

Comment: Quick update - Drive team confirmed this is a bug. No ETA for a fix.